# PowerShell: Unexplained leading white space when string from function is returned as assigned in another string variable

Tags: powershell

### Update

While I learned a quicker way to solve the problem below from the comments below, it is still unclear why this is occurring at all. After experimentation, I discovered that my failure to assign values to `[string] $return` and `[char] $trailingBackslash` (lines 10-11) at the start of `Remove-TrailingBackslashIfPresent` was the problem. If values are assigned (including `$null`) or the variables are deleted, the function will return a string and it will be assigned as a string in the main function.

I realize that PowerShell doesn't require variables to be declared. However, I do it out of habit so I can keep track of variables in my scripts.

So, I am modifying this question to understand **why uninitialized variables result in a string type not being assigned to a variable when returned from a function that returns a string?** I will start initializing variables when I declare then but the why would be nice to know and understand.

---

### Original Problem

### Overview

I have a function that is returning a string value as it is supposed to who but when it is assigned to another string variable in another function, it becomes an array object. I do not know why or how to fix it.

### Setup

I have written two functions. One is the main function `MyScript` which requires the user to enter as string (which is a Windows path). Then, `MyScript` passes that string to another function, `Remove-TrailingBackslashIfPresent`, whose job is to check if the string has a trailed backslash and if so, return the string without it. However, for a reason unknown to me, the string that is returned from the function `Remove-TrailingBackslashIfPresent` becomes an array once it is assigned to another string variable in `MyScript`. Effectively, the newly assigned variable has leading white space. While having code that executes as expected is always important, in my case, the string represents a Windows path. In `MyScript` I have included `(Test-Path -Path "$myString")` both before and after the `Remove-TrailingBackslashIfPresent` is called. Since `Remove-TrailingBackslashIfPresent` is only supposed to remove trailing backslashes, the `Test-Path` should come back `true` both times.

### Debugging Info

I have included both the main function `MyScript` and the function processing the string for a backslash,  `Remove-TrailingBackslashIfPresent` below. I have also included screenshots of debugging at two key points. First, at line 27 in the function `Remove-TrailingBackslashIfPresent`, it can seen seen in the debugger that the value being returned (`$return: "C:\Windows"`) is a string without leading white space. However, once assigned to the variable `$a` in `MyScript`, `$a` is an array object with three fields (`$a: [Object[3]]`). Lastly, I have included the output in PS terminal.

Why is this behavior occurring and what can I do to fix it (i.e. what syntax should I use in similar situations to avoid this happening in the future)? Thanks!

```
01: function Remove-TrailingBackslashIfPresent
02: {
03:     # SYNTAX: Remove-TrailingBackslash [-inputString] <string>
04:     [CmdletBinding()]
05:     param
06:     (
07:         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$inputString
08:     )
09: 
10:     [string] $return
11:     [char] $trailingBackslash
12: 
13:     $inputLen=$inputString.Trim().Length
14: 
15:     if ($inputLen -le 1)
16:     {
17:         return $inputString
18:     }
19:     else
20:     {
21:         $lastChar=$lastChar=("$inputString".trim().Substring("$inputString".Trim().Length-1,1))
22: 
23:         if ($lastChar -eq '\') {$return=("$inputString".trim().Substring(0,"$inputString".Trim().Length-1))}
24:         else {$return="$inputString"}
25: 
26:         
27:         "$return"
28:     }
29: }
30:
```

---

```
31: function MyFunction
32: {
33:     [CmdletBinding()]
34:     param
35:     (
36:         [Parameter()][string]$myString
37:     )
38: 
39:     $testA=(Test-Path -Path "$myString")
40:     Write-Output "A: $myString ==> $testA"
41: 
42:     $isroot=$false
43:     if (!($isRoot))
44:     {
45:         [string]$a
46:         $a=(Remove-TrailingBackslashIfPresent "$myString")
47:     }
48:     $testB=(Test-Path -Path "$a")
49:     Write-Output "B: $myString ==> $testB"
50: 
51:     $myString=$a
52: }
```

### Debugging at Line 27

[image]

### Debugging at Line 51

[image]

### PS Output

[image]

Comment: `$myString.TrimEnd( [char[]]'\ ' )` should do the job…

Comment: You don't even need to cast the backslash: `$String.TrimEnd('\')` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the specific problem at hand. However, as I write functions that often return a string, understanding why this is happening is still important. After much experimentation, I have discovered the problem lies with the variables `[string] $return` and `[char[ $trailingBackslash` in `Remove-TrailingBackslashIfPresent`. While I realize that I do not need to declare variables in PowerShell, it is a habit so I can keep track of variables. If I assign `$null` to each variable (or remove then), the problem goes away. Any idea why?